# How to add gender option in woocommerce edit account page and use it for showing specific content

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for the correct way to add radio gender option in woocommerce edit account page and use it for displaying specific content based on the options, that is male or female.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the body of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this . Add this below lines your current active theme functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'add_gender_to_edit_account_form' );
function add_gender_to_edit_account_form() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    ?>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="favorite_color"><?php _e( 'Gender', 'woocommerce' ); ?>

         <input type="radio" <?php if($user->user_gender=='male') { checked="checked" <?php } ?> name="user_gender" value="male"> Male<br>
         <input type="radio" <?php if($user->user_gender=='female') { checked="checked" <?php } ?> name="user_gender" value="female"> Female<br>

    </p>
    <?php
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_gender_account_details', 12, 1 );
function save_gender_account_details( $user_id ) {
    // For Favorite color
    if( isset( $_POST['user_gender'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_gender', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['user_gender'] ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late on my own question. I found the solution and would like to share it.

I used this code in my-account/form-edit-account.php to display gender option.

```html
<p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
    <select name="gender" id="gender">
        <option value="Male" <?php selected('Male', get_user_meta($user->ID, 'gender', true)); ?>>Male</option>
        <option value="Female" <?php selected('Female', get_user_meta($user->ID, 'gender', true)); ?>>Female</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Code for updating usermeta placed in functions.php

```html
add_action('woocommerce_save_account_details', 'custom_woocommerce_save_account_details');
function custom_woocommerce_save_account_details($user_id) {
    if ($user_id) {
        if (isset($_POST['gender'])) {
            if ($_POST['gender'] == 'Male' || $_POST['gender'] == 'Female') {
                update_user_meta($user_id, 'gender', $_POST['gender']);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I used this user meta information to display specific gender based content. Here is the code:

```html
<?php 
     $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
     $key = 'gender'; 
     $single = true; 
     $gender = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
     ?>
    <?php if ($gender == 'Female') { ?>
     // Content for female
    <?php } else { ?>
    // content for male
<?php } ?>
```